# Animate div-height depending from scrolling, without lag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, height

I have some sections and want to set the height of a separate div (fixed) depending to the scrolling (for a parallax effect). Every scroll action `$(window).scroll(function() {...});` the following code is fired. That works fine, but very laggy, because of the CPU usage, I think.
You know how to get the whole thing into the GPU usage with translate or something else.

```
        var windowHeight = $(window).height();
        var sectionNumber = 0;

        $("main section").each(function() {
            sectionNumber++;
            var secPosition = $(this).position();
            if( ( $(window).scrollTop() + windowHeight ) > secPosition.top ) {
                var secScrollValue = ($(window).scrollTop() + windowHeight) - secPosition.top;
                $(".parallaxBg" + sectionNumber).css("height", (windowHeight - secScrollValue) + "px");
            } else {
                $(".parallaxBg" + sectionNumber).css("height", "100%");
            }
        });
```

the parallax divs (without the section-numbers):

```
.parallaxBg {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background-position: 0px 0px;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-image: ...;
}
```

**Here is a sample:** http://jsfiddle.net/c5axqoo1/
On retina and with more content its a way more laggy!

Why I used `height`? Because I want the `background-position` fixed.

Pre-Thanks :)

Comment: Can you set up a working example?

Comment: Sample is here: http://jsfiddle.net/c5axqoo1/

Comment: Still looking for different solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You could animate translateY so it uses GPU

Here's a plugin that can might help you:
http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/

Comment: Testes that, but no cool result. The animation is delayed to the scrolling.

Comment: Have you tried easing or lowering the speed of the animation?

Comment: Ah ok, well that worked. Its a way better than the .css() from jquery. Thank you. But is there still a better way.

Comment: I think the lag is because of the great amount of data(html/images) you are moving. you could try to split the elements on visibility and just move the visible parts

Comment: Yeah, at the moment I just hide everything, that is currently not completely in the viewport.